# ¿Como impedir al usuario registrar una asistencia duplicada con la misma fecha?

Tags: mysql

Buen dia, estoy desarrollando para la universidad un pequeño sistema de asistencia, donde tengo la tabla de personal y asistencia, que pasa, que yo necesito que el sistema me deje agregar la asistencia diaria de cada empleado, PERO, no debe permitirme guardar dos o mas asistencias del mismo dia, como haria para realizar eso?, dejo una imagen de la tabla asistencia, donde el id_personal es el empleado que si se puede repetir pero, la columumna de **fecha** no deberia dejarme tener el mismo valor con el empleado dos veces repetido. Ayuda :(

[image: Tabla de Asistencia]

este es el codigo sql funcionando:

```html
$sql="INSERT INTO asistencia (id_personal, cod_asistencia, fecha, date_added) VALUES ('$id_personal','$cod_asistencia','$fecha','$date_added')";
  $query_new_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   if ($query_new_insert){
    $messages[] = "La asistencia ha sido ingresada satisfactoriamente.";
   } else{
    $errors []= "Lo siento, algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.".mysqli_error($con);
   }
  } else {
   $errors []= "Error desconocido.";
  }
  
  if (isset($errors)){
   
   ?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
     <strong>Error!</strong> 
     <?php
      foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
       }
      ?>
   </div>
   <?php
   }
   if (isset($messages)){
    
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
      <?php
       foreach ($messages as $message) {
         echo $message;
        }
       ?>
    </div>
    <?php
   }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo que podrías hacer es crear una función para validar sí ya se realizó el registro o no:

```
function validarAsistencia($id_personal, $fechaHoy){
$sql = "SELECT id_asistencia FROM asistencia WHERE id_personal = '".$id_personal."' 
AND date_added = '".$fechaHoy."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

   if ($result != null) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Y ya cuando vayas a realizar el insert:

```
if(validarAsistencia(1, '2019-01-01')){
    $query_new_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}else{
    echo "YA se realizó el registro";
}
```

Comment: si me sirvió amigo mil gracias

Answer (score 1):

Deberias haber creado la tabla con un clave primaria que tambien contemple la fecha, por ejemplo con un script similar a este:

```
CREATE TABLE asistencia(
   cod_asistencia INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   id_personal INT NOT NULL,
   fecha Datetime NOT NULL,
   ... (otros campos de la tabla
   PRIMARY KEY ( id_personal, fecha )
);
```

Esto hará que a la hora de insertar registros que tengan un mismo id_personal en una misma fecha, el propio MySQL te va a devolver un error.

Adicionalmente puedes controlarlo en el código php, pero yo empezaría por la BBDD.

Comment: probe con esa opcion, pero, no me deja añadir mas asistencias con otro personal, y necesito agregar ejemplo 10 empleados diarios con la misma fecha, pero, no dos empleados con la misma fecha.  Me entiende?

Comment: @Yosmar de hecho la restricción que te propone es lo que describes en tu pregunta, lo que no permite repetir es la **combinación** *empleado-fecha*.

Comment: ¿Qué ventaja tendría cambiar la clave primaria sobre añadir una restricción de unicidad en este caso?

Comment: @Alvaro, pues seguramente ninguna, es la forma más fácil que se me ha ocurrido. De hecho en tablas donde la unicidad es para mas de dos columnas yo casi nunca las uso como clave primaria y prefiero usar un id.

Answer (score 0):

En MySQL tienes la opción de llaves únicas, entonces en la Estructura de la Base puedes elegir a que campo los quieres único y que no se repita entonces te recomiendo que selecciones el id_personal y el date_added pero en una sola no separado.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio. Gracias por tomar el tiempo en responder, pero tu respuesta se asemeja mas a un comentario por favor revisa [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)